# DevOps Stages To Deploy

Tags: azure-devops, devops

I have a question about how we should perform the deployment of applications through automation (DevOps). I have seen examples where when doing a pull request to the master branch two environments QA and Production are deployed and I have also seen other examples where only deployed to Production and no longer the UAT environment. Is there any good practice that tells you what the ideal scenario is? Personally I see the procedure of double deployment unnecessary when doing the pull to master, because we assume that for this your application previously passed through a quality environment and was tested correctly otherwise it would not be going to master.

I include two images to try to graph more or less what I mean.

[image: Example 1]
[image: Example 2]
<sub>(source: [microsoft.com](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/_img/get-started-designer/rename-release-pipeline-azure-devops-newnavon.png?view=tfs-2018))</sub>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any good practice that tells you what the ideal scenario is?

I am afraid that should be hard for us to tell you the good practice what the ideal scenario is.

Whether we deploy to different phases in parallel depends on the actual needs of our project.

As we know, each stage represents one deployment target, though that target could be a physical or virtual server, a groups of servers, or any other legitimate physical or virtual deployment target. For example, if we build a pipeline, and we have to deploy it two or more environment, like windows, MAC. In this case, we should create two or more stage in parallel.

On the other hand, if we need more testing for the build result before we deploy the pipeline to the Production or Development stage, in this case, we need deploy to the QA stage before the Production or Development stage.

You can check the [Define your multi-stage continuous deployment (CD) pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/define-multistage-release-process?view=azure-devops) for some details.

If I do not understand your problem correctly, please let me know for free.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, I think the same way. The deployment strategy depends on the need you have.

Comment: Improving the answer: another variable to include in this equation is the maturity of the team and the architecture of the company. Teams with less maturity in devops or architectures more monolithic’s have more need to deploy in various environments, because of the difficulties for apply the test pyramid. In teams with more maturity and architectures more modern and decoupled, we can use a trunk-based approach without the need to deploy in various environments.